# QDomDocument can't open an content with an & in the text

Tags: c++, xml, qt

My problem is the following:

I open an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
  <C>A</C>
  <D>212</D>
  <E>Test1 & Test2</E>
</A>
```

It is not possible to set the Content like the following:

```
xmlFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text;

 QDomDocument doc("mydocument");
 if (!doc.setContent(xmlFile, &msg, &line, &col)) {
       qDebug()-><<"Failure in Column: "<<(QString)col<<"  Line: "+(QString)line;
       return false;
   }
```

If I remove the & from the XML File I can set the content.

WHY?

Comment: AFAIK, your example file is invalid XML. The `&` has to be expressed as `&amp;`.

Comment: The problem is that I'm just allowed to read the XML and in the XML the & is declared as stated in the example! Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: You might want to use your own `QXmlErrorHandler` and recover from the error somehow. Not sure if it's possible. Another option would be to pre-process the file and convert the `&` to `&amp;` on the fly.

Comment: Is there any other solution? because my XML file has about 350.000 lines and more.

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid XML. You should replace & with entity `&amp;`
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
<C>A</C>
<D>212</D>
<E>Test1 &amp; Test2</E>
</A>
```

You can validate XML with [online validation service](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

[List](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-predefined-ent) of XML pre-defined entities.

Comment: So I red a little bit about this topic, but the thing is, to come to an fast result, how can I implement this entity in my XML? I found just some theoretical stuff

Comment: ´&amp;´ is a pre-defined entity, you don't have to implement that.